# PUT file to S3 with Presigned URL and header: x-amz-checksum-sha256 return 403

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, put, sha256, pre-signed-url

We are trying to implement object integrity check for S3 PUT operations with SHA256 checksum. For multipart upload requests, this feature seems to work if we pass the SHA256 checksum in the CompleteMultipartUploadAsync methods

```
 var completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = key,
            UploadId = uploadId,
            ChecksumSHA256 = sha256ofFile
        };
completeRequest.AddPartETags(parts.Select(p => new PartETag(p.PartNumber, p.ETag)).ToArray());
await amazonS3Client.CompleteMultipartUploadAsync(completeRequest);
```

We are using the following code for  uploading small files

```
public async Task SimplePutAsync(string presignedURL , ByteArrayContent content , string sha256ofFile)
    {
        var  httpClient = new HttpClient();
        content.Headers.Add("x-amz-checksum-sha256", sha256ofFile);
        var response =  await httpClient.PutAsync(presignedURL, content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
```

if we specify the header: "x-amz-checksum-sha256" with the SHA256 value ,we get the error : 403 Forbidden

Also found the following post of AWS rePost

https://repost.aws/questions/QUgivVIUn6QrGVpETR1wQ4KQ/s-3-sha-256-checksum-for-presigned-url-in-file-upload

It mentions about ways of adding checksum headers to presigned url, but in the AmazonS3Client class in .NET SDK,

1. I cannot find equivalent method for generate_presigned_post
2. The Metadata property in GetPreSignedUrlRequest seems to be read only. So cannot use that in  GetPreSignedURL method
3. There is a parameter called additionalProperties in GeneratePreSignedURL, but there is no proper documentation

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you add the code you’re using for the ‘simple upload’ please?

Comment: Updated the initial post

Answer (score 0):

Though the `Metadata` property is readonly, you can *add* records to the MetaData object on the PreSignedUrlRequest:

```
var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest {
    BucketName = "bucket-name",
    Key = "key-name.ext",
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8),
    Verb = verb,
};
request.Metadata.Add("testing", "value");
```